# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget while adding GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I can't seem to understand what exactly is my error and how do I diagnose it,  How can I use the issue with the error-causing widget?
when I add this line to my code In this case `GestureDectector` I get the errors as mentioned below.
Could you please take a look?

```
 GestureDetector(
       onTap: () {
           BlocProvider.of<AppCubits>(context).getData();
             },
```

gives me the following error

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a ConstrainedBox widget.
```

full code, the error is gone when I remove `GestureDetector`

```
class WelcomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WelcomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WelcomePageState createState() => _WelcomePageState();
}

class _WelcomePageState extends State<WelcomePage> {
  List images = [
    "welcome-one.png",
    "welcome-two.png",
    "welcome-three.png",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: images.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            //pageview builder helps slide
            return Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: double.maxFinite,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: AssetImage("img/" + images[index]))),
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150, left: 20, right: 20),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        AppLargeText(text: "Trips"),
                        AppText(
                          text: "Mountain",
                          size: 30,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 250,
                          child: AppText(
                            text:
                                "Mountain hikes gives you an incredible sense of freedom along with endurance text",
                            color: AppColors.textColor2,
                            size: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 40,
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            BlocProvider.of<AppCubits>(context).getData();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            child: ResponsiveButton(
                              width: 120,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: List.generate(3, (indexDots) {
                        return Container(
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                          width: 8,
                          height: index == indexDots ? 25 : 8,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            color: index == indexDots
                                ? AppColors.mainColor
                                : AppColors.mainTextColor,
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change value in onTap method :
From:

```
BlocProvider.of<AppCubits>(context).getData();
```

To:

```
BlocProvider.of<AppCubits>(context, listen: false).getData();
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Comment: I think problem in ResponsiveButton not in gesturedetector if you are using flex or expand wrap it with row or column widget to fix it

Answer (score 0):

A flexible button should always be wrapped around a row or column

```
 child: Row(
            children: [
             ResponsiveButton(
                width: 120,),],),
```